# How to add nodes of one instance of treeview to the another instance of same treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

How to populate the nodes into the newtreeview1 which is the instance of the another treeview1 ? The nodes which is added to the "newtreeview1" should be available in the first instance of the treeview1?

for example; if the treeview1 contains

```
   |-- Node1
        |-- Node2
           | -- Node3
        |-- Node4
```

the newtreeview1 should also have the above nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by cloning each node 
like this

```
    private void CopyNodes(TreeView srcTree, TreeView dstTree)
    {
        var ar = System.Array.CreateInstance(typeof(TreeNode), srcTree.Nodes.Count);
        treeView1.Nodes.CopyTo(ar, 0);
        foreach (TreeNode item in ar)
        {
            dstTree.Nodes.Add((TreeNode)item.Clone());
        }
    }
```

and call the function

```
CopyNodes(treeView1, treeView2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the nodes. Something like:

```
otherTreeView.Nodes.Add(node.Text);
```

Depending on what you want, you need to pick an [overload of the Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.add.aspx) that includes all the data you want to copy (key, text, and/or images). Just don't add the nodes directly, but instead their constituent parts.

Comment: ya. i tried that but it throws "The specified node cannot be added to a nodes collection that belongs to a different control." Exception

Comment: This exception is only thrown if you are adding the node directly.  Re-read Martinho's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the approach given in this below link and serialize your tree contents. Then construct a new treeview based on the serialized contents. A big of a long-winded approach I know but this is guaranteed to add all the hierarchial data properly into the second treeview.

[Save nodes from a treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375371/save-my-nodes-in-treeview)

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy the TreeView1 instance and add additional nodes. 
Same thing as shown below

```
TreeView2 = TreeView1;
TreeView2.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode());
```